# How to make an Approval step in Azure Logic app calling my own APIs similar to office365 approval connector?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, workflow, azure-logic-apps

I wanna build a small workflow using Azure Logic Apps that contains an "Approval" step, which is simply an API call in my own system, similar to office 365 approval connector.

However, from what I found on the internet, the only way to make a long running task in Azure Logic Apps is to use Webhooks.

In Webhooks, I could not set a value to the parameter I created "Bool-Approved".. so, How can I check it later in a condition step?

The other possible solution maybe is to use Swagger to have an "Bool-Approved" parameter. However, it does not support long running action!

What's the possible solution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, the way to do it is to use the Webhook action, and for that you need to implement the Subscribe/Unsubscribe pattern described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app). The webhook action will allow you to get any payload (via an HTTP Post) from the instance-based webhook you are subscribing to.

The points below are a summary of this blog post: 
https://www.mexia.com.au/correlation-identifier-pattern-on-logic-apps/

To implement the Subscribe/Unsubscribe Webhook pattern you need to consider:

- **Subscription store**: A database to store the unique message Id and the
  instance-based callback URL provided by the webhook action.
- **Subscribe and Start Request Processing API**: this is a RESTful API that is in charge of starting the processing of the request and storing the
  subscription.
- **Unsubscribe and Stop Request Processing API**: this is another RESTful API that is only going to be called if the webhook action on the main workflow times out. This API is in charge of stopping the processing and deleting the subscription from the store.
- **Instance-based webhook**: this webhook is to be triggered by your own custom approval event. Once triggered, your webhook is in charge of getting the instance-based callback URL from the store and invoking it. After making the call back to the main workflow instance, the subscription is to be deleted. This is the webhook that is in charge of sending the payload you require to the waiting webhook action in your Logic App.

The subsequent actions will be able to use that response body, so you can implement your conditions, etc.

You can follow the [blog post mentioned above](https://www.mexia.com.au/correlation-identifier-pattern-on-logic-apps/) to see a detailed example and get more details on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

make you api return HTTP code 200 if the response if "ok" and 400 if the response is "not ok". This way you can force logic app to behave the way you need it to behave..

Comment: Well, so can't I set a value to a parameter from the returned value in the callback?